# How can I get safe tx hash or safe tx detail by on chain transaction hash

Tags: gnosis-safe

As title.

I have a on chain transaction hash from gnosis safe and I need to get the detail info from the on chain transaction. But no interface to query safe transaction detail by on chain transaction hash. Anything I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Etherscan to input the transaction hash and view the details.

Alternatively, use a library like Web3.js or Ethers.js to query the transaction details from an Ethereum node.

The Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API doesn't support querying by on-chain transaction hash directly, but the above methods should work.

Good luck.